# Function keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to get this function to run for about an hour now and it is driving me insane.

Here is my JS file

```
function hannaford(){
 var x = document.getElementByName("hList").value;
 x =parseInt(x);
 var i;
var hannafordResp = ["Responsibility 1", "Responsibility 2", "Three", "Four", "Five"];
for(i=0; i<x-1; i++){
    document.getElementById("hannafordResult").innerHTML = (hannafordResp[i]) + "<br />"
}
```

}

Here is the relevant HTML code.

```
    <div class="experience clearfix">
    <h3>Hannaford Supermarkets</h3>
    <p>
    Position
    <br />
    Location
    <br /> <br />
    2013-2015
    </p>
    <p>How many responsibilities?(max 5)</p>
    <input type="text" name="hList" >
    <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="hannaford()" >

    <p id="hannafordResult"> </p>


    </div>
```

The error message I get is ReferenceError: hannaford() is not defined.

I have checked syntax thoroughly, but nothing seems to work. Any posibilities?

Comment: Probably `hannaford` is defined in a closure.

Comment: 1) Did you import the script properly? Using `<script src="script.js"/>` does not work, for instance. 2) Does `hannaford()` have an ending `}`? Your posted code does not.

Answer (score 4):

Go ahead and run this code snippet.  You needed to use `getElementsByName` (you were using `Element`).  This returns an array, so you need to get the 0th return's value.

Then your for-loop should be going to x, not x-1

```js
function hannaford(){
  var x = document.getElementsByName("hList")[0].value;
  x =parseInt(x);
  var i;
  var hannafordResp = ["Responsibility 1", "Responsibility 2", "Three", "Four", "Five"];
  for(i=0; i<x; i++){
    document.getElementById("hannafordResult").innerHTML = (hannafordResp[i]) + "<br />"
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="experience clearfix">
  <h3>Hannaford Supermarkets</h3>
  <p>
    Position
    <br />
    Location
    <br /> <br />
    2013-2015
  </p>
  <p>How many responsibilities?(max 5)</p>
  <input type="text" name="hList" >
  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="hannaford()" >

  <p id="hannafordResult"> </p>


</div>
```